# What is the mechanism of subharmonic oscillations?

Tags: oscillators, resonance, non-linear-systems, harmonics, anharmonic-oscillators

It's clear to me from linear systems theory that energy manifested within a fundamental mode of resonance can saturate with the excess energy spilling over into harmonic frequencies greater than the fundamental. The saturation though is a nonlinear behavior.

But I've read (somewhere?) that there can be nonlinear behavior in the system where the energy can find it's way into subharmonics - modes with frequencies lower than the fundamental.

So is this nonlinearity also saturation of the fundamental? What are specific nonlinear structures or mechanisms of a system that can lead to these subharmonic oscillations?

Is there a simple model that connects with real physical systems where I can study this type of behavior?

Comment: It is easy to create subharmonics with a digital circuit e.g. the bistable two-transistor circuit here http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html. These are rather easy to analyze, too, certainly a lot easier than many of the non-linear systems that are favorites among theoretical physicists. Something tells me, though, that this isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: There is a nonlinear wave-wave decay in plasmas where a Langmuir-like wave decays into another Langmuir-like wave (at lower frequency) and an ion-acoustic wave (with frequency equal to the difference between mother/daughter Langmuir waves).  Is this the type of thing for which you are looking?